# XmlMap.Import without using Interopt

Tags: c#, excel, xml

I've defined an Excel template using Xml mappings that will generate the Excel report based on the Xml that I import.

I need to generate this report on the server so I can't use Microsoft Interopt. How can I do the following (C#) with an open source library?

```
Application excel = new Application();

Workbook workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "TestTemplate.xlsx"));

var result = workbook.XmlMaps[1].Import(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "TestData.xml"), true);

workbook.Save();

workbook.Close();
excel.Workbooks.Close();
```

This allows me to do formatting of the Excel sheet on my own PC (with Office 365) and then save the template and publish with the project and just update the XML data and save as a new report.

Comment: Use oledb driver (or ACE if have office).  See : https://www.connectionstrings.com/excel/

Comment: But how @jdweng?

Comment: See msdn : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection?force_isolation=true&view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0

Answer (score 0):

I ended up going with [`ClosedXML`](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML.Report)'s reporting plugin that has a variable replacement function that ended up working just as well.

The example from their website:

```
protected void Report()
{
    const string outputFile = @".\Output\report.xlsx";
    var template = new XLTemplate(@".\Templates\report.xlsx");

    using (var db = new DbDemos())
    {
        var cust = db.customers.LoadWith(c => c.Orders).First();
        template.AddVariable(cust);
        template.Generate();
    }

    template.SaveAs(outputFile);

    //Show report
    Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(outputFile) { UseShellExecute = true });
}
```